# How do I change the ISO and shutter speed settings in Aperture Priority mode on a Canon DSLR?

Tags: canon, camera-settings, iso, aperture-priority

I am looking to change the ISO settings and shutter speed during the Aperture Mode in my Canon 77D.

[image: screenshot of menu selection]

I am not able to see this screen on my camera.

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Where did you find this screenshot with these menu options?

Answer (score 1):

When in the "Creative Zone" exposure modes (P, Tv, Av, M), you can select the ISO speed setting using the "ISO" button on top of the camera or by going to 'Menu → Shooting (red) Tab 2 → ISO Speed'.

When in the "Creative Zone" exposure modes (P, Tv, Av, M), you can select the maximum ISO speed limit by going to 'Menu → Shooting (red tab) 2 → ISO Auto', pressing the "Set" button, scrolling to the desired maximum ISO value between 400-25600, and pressing the "Set" button again.

The EOS 77D has no option to select a minimum shutter speed when shooting in the *Aperture Priority (Av)* exposure mode, nor does it have an option to select the range of ISO speed settings that will be available when using the ISO button or 'Menu → Shooting (red tab) 2 → ISO Speed' option to set the ISO speed. Higher Canon EOS models offer these features.

Answer (score 0):

For Canon EOS 77D there is no such option. The only setting is to set maximum ISO when in AutoISO, page 160 of [Instruction manual](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/3/0300026603/01/EOS_77D_Instruction_Manual_EN.pdf)
[image]

Comment: Why wouldn't the settings made following the procedure on page 160 of the *Instruction Manual* not apply when in *Aperture Priority (Av)* exposure mode?

Comment: @MichaelC, they apply. There is no option to set minimum ISO and minimum shutter speed.

Comment: I don't think any of Canon's EOS cameras offer an option to set minimum ISO speed (other than whether to enable extended L or not, which is a separate setting). The choices are always ISO 100-xxxx (i.e. ISO 100-1600, ISO 100-3200, ISO 100-6400, etc.).

Comment: I understand English is not your primary language. But your answer opens by saying "you can't do *any* of that", then tells how one may do *some* of that.

Comment: I see @MichaelC, my intention was to say OP can't do the full setting. And 77D offer only maximum.

Comment: @MichaelC, about minimum ISO it can be 200,400 and so on. Check page 123 here: http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/4/0300012004/04/EOS_70D_Instruction_Manual_EN.pdf (Canon 70D)

Comment: Hah! It seems all of my Canon cameras released since about 2012 have that option and I'd totally forgotten it.